# Is it possible to use drone in periodic pull mode?

Tags: drone.io

So we have an environment that can't be accessed without a VPN and we want to use drone there but at this situation we can't use webhooks. Is it possible to make drone periodically check our scm and if there's new commit it should start doing its work?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CRON feature to periodically build. The documentation has more details here: https://docs.drone.io/cron/.

Alternatively, if the Drone server and runner are inside of a VPN, you could publish events to something like Amazon Web Services SQS to push the messages and then [poll the SQS queue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-short-and-long-polling.html) from inside of the VPN to ping the internal Drone server.